# Push arrays into one JSON array

Tags: jquery, arrays, push

I'm trying to push two whole arrays into one array.

The two arrays are named "quiz" and "t", how do I push them into "canvas"? Am I totally out of logic here or what am I missing? :)

```
var canvas = {};

canvas.push({
    QuizModule: quiz,
    Elements: t
    });

json_elements = JSON.stringify({Elements: canvas }, null, "\t");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be `[]` not `{}`. Push is applied on the array `[]` not on object `{}`.

```
var canvas = [];

canvas.push({
    QuizModule: quiz,
    Elements: t
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

push() is a function for Arrays, not Objects.

If you want to keep canvas as an Object, you could use extend() from Underscore.js (http://underscorejs.org/#extend):

```
_.extend(canvas, { QuizModule: quiz, Elements: t });
```

jQuery extend() would to the same.